# AngularJS how to put both ng-class and CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an element which has static CSS classes and dynamic classes which will be determined by a method, so how do I put them together?

I tried below code, but it does not work:

```
<div class="static-class" ng-class="{'dynamic-class': isEnabled()}"></div>
```

So as a workaround I did this:

```
<div ng-class="{'static-class': true, 'dynamic-class': isEnabled()}"></div>
```

But this is ugly, especially when there are many static classes.

**EDIT**
**I found my first example works! Sorry for for this question.**

Comment: Are you sure your first example does not work ? I've been doing it this way for some time without problem.

Comment: The first example work, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/PrmRL/1/ , however that's assuming `isEnabled()` works.

Comment: Your example works even with Angular version 1.0.1 : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/PrmRL/3/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your first example should work:

```
<div class="static-class" ng-class="{'dynamic-class': isEnabled()}"></div>
```

Alternatively you can also use:

```
<div class="static-class ng-class: {'dynamic-class': isEnabled()};"></div>
```